# How to customize Moodle default login page UI?

Tags: moodle

I just set up Moodle 3.82 (Build: 20200309) on the development server.

Now I wonder if I can change the login page (using Classic theme).

Here's the current login page:
[image]

It's supposed to be changed into this:
[image]

What are the required CSS files (and probably PHP/JS as well) which have to modified?

I already take a look inside **\theme\classic** directory and at **Site administration -> Appearance -> Themes -> Classic**.

Still no idea, though.

Answer (score 3):

Changing files that came with the installation is not advisable as it could break the upgrade feature or at best make you lose changes if you do manage to upgrade.

You could create a new barebones theme that completely inherits the "Classic" theme (we'll call it "mynewtheme") and then only change the login form by following these instructions:

1. Create you barebones theme here: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Overriding_a_renderer but basing it on "Classic" instead of "standard,base" written here (so $THEME->parents should say just "classic" instead of "standard", "base" as in the example). You can ignore the part from where it says "About html_writer" and onwards. Logout, login and the screen will tell you it will install the new theme. Click on "Upgrade moodle database", go to Site administration -> Appearance -> Themes -> Theme selector and choose your theme so you can see it works and see the changes.
2. Create a template that overrides the current login template by going into your new theme's directory creating a directory called templates, inside that creating a directory called core and copy the file called "loginform.mustache" from the boost/templates/core directory (because classic inherits from it) so you get mynewtheme/templates/core/loginform.mustache. You can play around with the html and mustache until it looks right (if you are unfamiliar with the syntax, it can help to learn it from here https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html)
3. You can indicate css or scss files by adding them to the config.php file you created in step 1. above. If you want to use sass instead of css create a directory "sass" in your theme directory, put your .scss file there (say you called it "login.scss") and in config.php  have `$THEME->scss = 'login';` and it will get compiled and included. If you prefer css, create a directory called "style" in your theme directory, in that create a file with any name ending in .css and add just the name inside the $THEME->sheets array. So if you named it "login.css" have the line in config.php say `$THEME->sheets = ['login'];` After you changes you will need to refresh the moodle cache to see the changes by going to Site administration -> Appearance -> Themes -> Theme selector and click on "Clear theme caches" or to have the cache refresh with every page refresh in the browser go to Site administration -> Appearance -> Themes -> Theme settings, put a checkbox in "Theme designer mode" and save. But beware - it will make your site very slow so don't leave it on permanently.